# How to split words that start with a number and end with a word or vice versa using regex

Tags: regex, string, search, text, split

How to split words that start with a number and end with a word or vice versa using regex

```
example: manu ransu 12hul 3fo tho23 n23fs 23fdf. nu3

output: manu ransu 12 hul 3 fo tho 23 n23fs 23fdf. nu3
```

It should not split the word n23ffs as it starts with a alphabet and ends with an alphabet
It should not split the word 23fdf. as it starts with a number and ends with a symbol

Comment: What is your current regex flavor?

Comment: Why did `n3` not become `nu 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that symbols break matching makes this a tough regex to crack. Here it is:

`(?<=[^\S])((\d+)([a-zA-Z]+))(?=[^\S])|(?<=[^\S])(([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+))(?=[^\S])`

This big ugly monster uses forward and backward lookarounds to assert that there's no symbols at the beginning or end of a word.

`(?<=[^\S])` is a lookbehind to assert that the first character isn't a non-whitespace character, while its partner, `(?=[^\S])`, asserts the same of the last character in the match.

`(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)` checks for one or more digits followed by one or more letters. `([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)` does the same, for letter-number combos.

The `|` in the middle lets the regex check for either of these two patterns.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/bSNqPK/4/)